# How to login into windows 7 desktop programmatically in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create my own windows service to log on a user on windows 7 programmatically when it starts up. Without letting user to type the password.

I have a mobile application to verify the user once he/she starts the system, the service run before windows login screen, where it sends a verification link on the mobile app from there the user is verified through the mobile app, once the user is verified then I want my service to authenticate the user by clicking the auto login button which should automatically map the password to the windows login account to log on the system.
I am able to run my [windows service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucUbS.jpg) before the windows login screen, but not able to map the password to log on the system.

I have already gone through with [Credential Provider Samples](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4057)(the only option I found) but these samples are not showing there functionality.How to use these samples to implement.

Comment: How about just remove the password? Assuming this is a local user, you should be able to have a user with no password without any issues.

Comment: You can do this with a simply windows configuration change.  Why would you want to write a service?  http://superuser.com/q/28647/388890

Comment: @Joe Enos: Thanks for responding. Since we have to set up the active directory for which we need to join the domain and require a password for authentication.

Comment: Related – https://stackoverflow.com/q/32372027/1454514